# Проблема с кодировкой WebClient

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, azure, webclient

Написал простенького Telegram бота на C# для получения случайных анекдотов через API, деплоил на Azure.

Класс, реализующий команду получения и отправки анекдотов:

```
 public class JokeCommand : Command
    {
        public override string Name => "joke";

        public override async Task Execute(Message message, TelegramBotClient client)
        {
            var chatId = message.Chat.Id;
            

            try
            {
                string joke = GetJoke();                
                await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, joke);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private string GetJoke()
        {
            string url = "http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1";
            JObject json;            

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {                
                string response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
                json = JObject.Parse(response);

            }

            string joke = json["content"].ToString();                        
            return joke;
        }
    }
```

В телеграме получаю такой ответ:

> 

- Ñêàæèòå, - äîïûòûâàåòñÿ ìîëîäîé ïèñàòåëü ó ðåäàêòîðà, - åñòü
  âîîáùå íàäåæäà, ÷òî ìîé ðàññêàç ïîÿâèòñÿ â âàøåì æóðíàëå?
- Íó ðàçóìååòñÿ. Âñå ëþäè ñìåðòíû, è ÿ - íå âå÷åí.

> 

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема и как решить?

Comment: В кодировке, логично же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Известная проблема с кодировками в `WebClient.DownloadString`, там кодировку надо задавать явно. Для автоматического определения кодировки используйте `HttpClient`.

```cs
public class JokeCommand : Command
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public override string Name => "joke";

    public override async Task Execute(Message message, TelegramBotClient client)
    {
        var chatId = message.Chat.Id;
            
        try
        {
            string joke = await GetJokeAsync();                
            await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, joke);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetJokeAsync()
    {
        const string url = "http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1";
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return JObject.Parse(response)["content"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!